# Unclear manipulation with forcing conditions

Tags: set-theory, forcing

To this question in Kunen's introduction to independence proofs

> on the page 379, in the proof of lemma V.7.3 you never mention
>     $q$
>   in the proof, only
>   $p$;
>   why?
>   I cannot make sense of this simple proof and lemma.

I've received this answer:

> The claim is that there is a q extending p and
>   a countable subset B of kappa
>   such that q forces a certain property of B.
>
> The proof says that if there is no such q and B,
>   then p forces that in the generic extension,
>   there is no countable ground-model subset B of kappa
>   satisfying this property.
>
> And this last statement (which doesn't mention q)
>   leads to a contradiction.

BUT I still do not understand why we can get rid off q and say

> then p forces that in the generic extension,
>   there is no countable ground-model subset B of kappa
>   satisfying this property.

I may write down the details for those who do not have the book opened on the table, but I think that the context is almost clear from the question and the partial answer of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inductive definition of forcing (by complexity of formulas) gives in particular that $p$ forces $\lnot\psi$ if and only if no extension of $p$ forces $\psi$. That is exactly what is being claimed.

As for *why* this general fact about forcing of negations holds, it is either immediate from the fact that a statement holds in a generic extension if and only if some member of the generic forces it, or else one needs to delve into the ground model characterization of the forcing relation. The latter is done in detail in Kunen's book.

Comment: Could you please give me the number of the relevant page of that "detail in Kunen's book" ?

Comment: There is a whole chapter devoted to details of forcing. It is more beneficial if you actually look through it than if I do.

Comment: I really cannot skim through almost 400 pages to find such a detail. Can you mention here at least the title of the relevant subchapter? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Is it the "Truth lemma" on the page 251??

Comment: @user122424 p.244--263 are relevant to your question.

Comment: @StefanMesken Could you please sepcify the concrete theorem in Kunen's book which states this: "either $p$ forces $\phi$ or some extension of $p$ forces not $\phi$"?

Comment: @user122424 Even if I could point to such a theorem, I wouldn't. Because it's not in your best interest. If you want to know how to force, you need to learn how forcing works. And reading Kunen's chapter on forcing is by far the most convenient way to learn the basics that I know of. Like Andrés said before, this fact will follow from the definition of the forcing relation.